# Adding Points to ordiplot3d()

Tags: r, rgl, vegan

I am making a PCA with `vegan{}` and I would also like to label my points by factors (instead of by their unique row identities, as is the default for `biplot.rda()`). For my 2D PCAs I have used the method suggested [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Different-labels-for-subsets-of-points-in-a-PCA-or-RDA-biplot-td880695.html) by Gavin Simpson. I would like to ask the wise R community whether there is a 3D version of this method for creating a custom-labeled PCA. 
Here's the method that works for 2D PCAs:

```
#Relabel a la Gavin Simpson:
site.scr<-scores(dat.pca,display="sites",scaling=2,choices=c(1,2,3))
spp.scr<-scores(dat.pca,display="species",scaling=2,choices=c(1,2,3))

## generate x,y lims
xlims <- range(site.scr[,1], spp.scr[,1])
ylims <- range(site.scr[,2], spp.scr[,2])

## plot what you want, but leave out sites
biplot(dat.pca, display = "species", xlim = xlims, ylim = ylims)
points(site.scr[39:65,2:3],col="green",pch=1)   #These sites are in green
points(site.scr[1:38,2:3],col="brown",pch=3)        #These sites are in brown
```

I have done this using `ordirgl()` on one of my computers, but there are some R version/OS combos that don't play well with rgl (this seems to be an issue for a number of people), so I want to be able to make the plot in both `rgl()` and `ordiplot3d()`

```
ordiplot3d(dat.pca, display = "species", scaling = 3)
```

This plots points onto the 3D space instead of the vectors that biplot.rda (first issue-- I also have this problem when I use rgl-- I think these points are the ends of the vectors that plot in a normal `biplot.rda()` PCA). This is not as much of a concern to me, but if anyone knows how to draw these vectors in ordirgl and label them, I'd like to know.
The bigger issue is that I am having a hard time adding points to ordiplot3d once it's made. Ideally this would be something like `points()`.  I've seen this in a few different question threads, but it would be nice to have an elegant solution that doesn't require rgl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a warning; at the moment the underlying code used to draw the 3d biplots (package **scatterplot3d**) does not allow us to scale *all* axes the same. Hence the biplot is not correct as the third dimension cannot be scaled in the same units as the other two. Jari has provided a patch to the maintainer of the **scatterplot3d** package that allows this to be controlled but we are waiting on it being accepted etc.

What you are missing is that `ordiplot3d()` (because of its use of `scatterplot3d()`) returns an object that contains functions that allow you to add points etc to an existing 3d scatterplot.

Here is an example

```
## continue example from ?biplot.rda
require(vegan)
## produces 'mod' 
example(biplot.rda)
## why do we need this?
par(ask = FALSE)

## grab the scores on axes you require; mod == your fitted rda/pca 
site.scr <- scores(mod, display = "sites", scaling = 3, choices = 1:3) 
spp.scr <- scores(mod, display = "species", scaling = 3, choices = 1:3)

## do the 3d plot but suppress plotting of the species,
## though plot is scaled to accommodate them
ordi <- ordiplot3d(mod, display = "species", scaling = 3, type = "n")
```

Now look at the object `ordi` it is a complex object returns functions that allow you to add points to the current plot:

```
> str(ordi, max = 1)
List of 7
 $ xyz.convert   :function (x, y = NULL, z = NULL)  
 $ points3d      :function (x, y = NULL, z = NULL, type = "p", ...)  
 $ plane3d       :function (Intercept, x.coef = NULL, y.coef = NULL, lty = "dashed", lty.box = NULL, 
    ...)  
 $ box3d         :function (...)  
 $ origin        : num [1, 1:2] 1.67 1.33
 $ envfit.convert:function (object)  
 $ points        : num [1:30, 1:2] -0.146 2.776 1.291 3.102 2.816 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "ordiplot3d" "ordiplot"
```

Now by way of illustration, plot the first 10 species with a colour and a a circle, second ten with a different colour and plotting character etc. using the `points3d()` returned:

```
cols <- bgs <- c("red","green","blue")
pchs <- 21:23
ordi$points3d(spp.scr[1:10,1], spp.scr[1:10,2], spp.scr[1:10,3],
              col = cols[1], bg = bgs[1], pch = pchs[1])
ordi$points3d(spp.scr[11:20,1], spp.scr[11:20,2], spp.scr[11:20,3],
              col = cols[2], bg = bgs[2], pch = pchs[1])
ordi$points3d(spp.scr[21:30,1], spp.scr[21:30,2], spp.scr[21:30,3],
              col = cols[3], bg = bgs[3], pch = pchs[3])
```

which produces:

[image: example of adding points to a 3d scatterplot]

Though do please note that this is not a real biplot as the scaling on the 3rd axis (z) is wrong until the ability to have equal scaling is added to `scatterplot3d()`.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I will look for the patched version and in the meantime, I guess rgl is the only one that will have accurate scaling.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a small package called pca3d (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pca3d/index.html) which also can create 3D biplots. I scales the samples and the variables independently, therefore the variable loadings are directly comparable. However, it is beta, so beware.

[image]